# Trying to prove $f'$ has no zero for a 2-to-1 function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open and $f$ is holomorphic and 2-to-1 in $U$ (i.e. for each $w \in f(U)$ there are exactly 2 points $z_1 \neq z_2$ s.t. $f(z_1)=f(z_2)=w$), then $f'$ has no zero in $U$.

I thought in analogy of real case where this statement is "partially" true if we just consider extrema. In real case it is possible that the critical point is not an extremum, and we can build 2-to-1 function with such points, but my intuition tells me that analogy of such point in complex will make this function not holomorphic at this point. In real case derivative is either positive or negative if it is not $0$, so it is easy to keep track of it. However I failed to continue with this analogy idea. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $f'(a)=0$ (and $f$ is nonconstant in a neighborhood of $a$). Then i) near $a,$ $f(z) = f(a) + c_m(z-a)^m + \cdots $ where $m\ge 2,$ and ii) there is a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f$ is exactly $m$-to-one in $U\setminus \{a\}.$